# Math function for plotting a surface that looks like crumpled paper?

Tags: surfaces, complex-dynamics

Is there a way to draw a two-dimensional or three-dimensional surface that resembles [this](https://unsplash.com/photos/P6rShCD6Sx4)?

All I know so far is that [the dynamics of  paper are more complicated than they sound](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/26/science/crumple-paper-math.html), does this mean I could only get it with a physics simulator?

Comment: I am unable to visualize the document but I can give you the reference of Damien Rohmer and colleagues at Ecole Polytechnique (Paris) who have done research on this theme. See in particular on his webpage https://imagecomputing.net/damien.rohmer/research/publications/index.html his 2015 publications (Interactively animating crumbling paper, etc.)

Comment: If you're asking for a physically accurate model of how paper crumbles, then you're on the wrong site (this is more of a physics question). If you just want a mathematical object which kind of looks like this, then I guess look for a graph $z=f(x,y)$ of a continuous, piecewise affine function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$